# Combustion properties of Dimethyl Ether

Tags: combustion, reference-request

I have a C++ code which calculates the combustion thermodynamic variables (temperature, density) and the mass fractions of Dimethyl Ether for different equivalence ratio. I would like to check my results but I couldn't find anything on google. Most of the papers about DME that I've found show the laminar flame speed.

Please refer me to some paper or book if you know any. A graph showing the adiabatic flame temperature vs equivalence ratio would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please refer me to some paper or book if you know any. A graph showing the adiabatic flame temperature vs equivalence ratio would be ideal.

In 2014 it appears that Glaude, Sirjean, Fournet et al. [published a paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01070016/document) that gives exactly the data you are looking for.  See Figure 4 from their paper, which I have also included below.

[image]

Possibly relevant text from the paper:

> the
>   maximum flame temperature is obtained for slightly rich
>   mixtures, at an equivalence ratio around 1.05-1.1, because of
>   the lower impact of dilution by nitrogen when the amount of
>   air decreases. At the strict stoichiometric conditions, the rate
>   of the endothermal molecular dissociations is also at its
>   maximum which tends to depress the temperature.

Also this next bit:

> The results show that alcohols have flame temperatures
>   comparable to those of conventional fuels, contrary to DME
>   that develops significantly higher temperatures. This is
>   consistent with the respective values of the heating values of
>   these fuels and thermochemical equilibrium data.
>
> I couldn't find anything on google.

I found the paper by Googling `dme adiabatic flame temperature`.

Comment: I never expected to get such a complete answer! Thank you for that. Also, I googled `dme adiabatic flame temperature` again just to be sure and did not find that paper. I guess google knows you better than me!